# How to Delete or Update on NOT EXISTS in MySql with Unique Key when there is a duplicate key conflict

Tags: mysql, not-exists, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to update a table that has a UNIQUE key based on three fields (PlayerId, TargetId, CampaignId).  I have a scenario where I will need to update one field, but that may create a duplicate (which then generates a duplication error).  I need to find a way to update only the records that do not create a conflict and either merge the duplicates or delete the duplicates.  I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE `assignments` SET `PlayerId`='45' WHERE `CampaignId`='3' AND `PlayerId`='2101'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM `assignments` WHERE `CampaignId`='3' AND `PlayerId`='2101' )
```

MySql error is:

```
#1093 - Table 'assignments' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

I then tried to create a query that would update if it was not a conflict and delete the others...something like

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY DELETE
```

Comment: you can try using aliases.

Comment: Tried this...didn't work...is this what you mean?   UPDATE `assignments` SET `PlayerId`='45' WHERE `CampaignId`='3' AND `PlayerId`='2101'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM `assignments` as `temp` WHERE `CampaignId`='3' AND `PlayerId`='2101' )

Comment: There are no duplicate record to your sample. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c145a/5)